# C# Android service crash without errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making an Android application in Xamarin. The application has a TCP listener that runs in the background. So this listener is still active when the application is not open I have moved it across to run as a service. Unfortunately when started the UI becomes unresponsive and crashes without throwing any errors in the debugger.

Starting the service on a new thread from an activity:

```
        btnStart.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
            Thread listener = new Thread (() => 
            {
                StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)));
            });
            listener.Start();
        };
```

And here is the code from the service:

```
    public override void OnStart(Android.Content.Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStart (intent, startId);
        Log.Debug ("Service Class", "Service has started");
        DoActions ();
    }

    public void DoActions()
    {
        Log.Debug("Service Class", "getting local IP!");
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) 
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString ();
                break;
            }
        }

        int port = 1111;
        IPAddress localaddr = IPAddress.Parse (localIP);
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener (localaddr, port);
        Log.Debug ("Service Class", "accepted local IP, starting listener");
        tcpListener.Start ();
        Log.Debug ("Service Class", "You are now listening on " + localaddr + port);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket ();
            byte[] array = new byte[1024];
            socket.Receive (array);
            string @string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (array);
            Log.Debug ("Service Class", "Message Received From Server:" + (@string.Replace ("\0", string.Empty)));
        }
    }
```

I get up to the "You are now listening on " + localaddr + port" debug message. In this case it is 192.168.0.105 port 1111. I had a timer write to the debug ever x seconds and I would get a few responses before the application crashed. This same TCP Listener works fine when I used to run it as a task from the same activity.

is there a way that I can send more information to the debugger to find out what is going wrong?
I am using a Tronsmart mk908b on 4.2.2 for testing

Thanks in advance!

Update:
It seems this might have something to do with Android service lifecycle. Still looking for a way to fix this.

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/di7V7AMM

Comment: Info(364)/InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{413e3dd0 u0 SecureX2.SecureX2/securex2.ListenActivity}.  It has been 5002.8ms since event, 5002.3ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.

Comment: within those 5 seconds if it gets a message it will print fine

Answer (score 0):

DO not start the service inside a thread.

```
    btnStart.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)));
    };
```

Comment: Thanks!. I was of the understanding that it would run on the ui thread if I were to do this. Testing now

Comment: same result: Info(364)/InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{414d29e0 u0 SecureX2.SecureX2/securex2.ListenActivity}.  It has been 5003.0ms since event, 5002.8ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.

Comment: @user1672867, did u get the answer ?